# web workers behave differently in webkit than Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, webkit

I have a web application that works just fine in modern webkit-based browsers ([http://montecarlo-tester.appspot.com/](http://montecarlo-tester.appspot.com)). Basically it uses a webworker to fetch data from a server, and then sends it back after performing some computations.

It works just fine in Chrome/Safari (no errors in console), but when I try to use it in Firefox, it doesn't. I've deduced that somehow the variable 'iterations' is not set properly in Firefox. Unfortunately, Firefox lacks a debugger (for web workers), and javascript has functional scoping, so it's really hard to pinpoint where the problem is. I've posted the javascript code for my web worker, and I was wondering if anybody could point out where I went wrong:

```
importScripts('/static/js/mylibs/jquery.hive.pollen-mod.js');


$(function (data) {
    main();
    //while(main());
    close();
});

function main() {
    //make an ajax call to get a param
    var iterations//value will be set by server response
    var key//key of the datastore object
    var continueloop = true;
    p.ajax.post({
        url:'/getdataurl',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(responseText){
            if (responseText === null) {
                var workermessage = {
                    "log":"responseText is null. Either the server has issues or we have run out of stuff to compute."
                };
                $.send(workermessage);
                continueloop = false;
            }
            iterations = responseText.iterationsjob;
            key = responseText.key;      
        }
    });

    if (continueloop === false) {
        return false;
    }

//here is where I think the problems begin. In chrome/safari, iterations = 1000. 
//In Firefox however, iterations = null. As a result, everything after that does not work.

    var i,x,y,z;
    var count = 0;
    var pi;
    start = new Date();
    for (i=0;i<iterations;i++) {
        x = Math.random();
        y = Math.random();
        z = x*x+y*y;
        if(z<=1.0){
            count++;
        }
    }//end for loop
    pi = count/(iterations)*4.0;
    end = new Date();
    result = {
        "estimated_pi":pi,
        "num_iter":iterations,
        "duration_ms":end.valueOf()-start.valueOf(),
        "key":key
    };
    //send results to the server
    p.ajax.post({
        url: "/resultshandler",
        dataType:'json',
        data: result,
        success: function()
        {
            //do nothing!
        }
    });
    $.send(result);
    return true;//persists the loop
}
```

Comment: "Unfortunately, Firefox lacks a debugger" Have you tried [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com)?

Comment: Does it make a difference to put a semicolon after your variable name before the comment for `var iterations` and `var key`?

Comment: Is your `p.ajax.post` function doing asynchronous or synchronous ajax?  If async, then `iterations` will only be set in your success handler, not where you're asking for it to be set because the ajax call hasn't completed yet so `iterations` isn't set yet.  Call an async ajax call just starts the operation and then your javascript continues executing.  It isn't completed until sometime later when the success handler runs.

Comment: It is possible that it could be a problem with async javascript, but it works perfectly in Chrome and only halfway in Firefox. If it was an async issue I would think that the results would be the same... I'm thinking that it has to do with implementation of scoping within  Firefox webworkers.

Comment: As I said in my comment before, if anyone is interested in taking over the project, just say so and I will make you a collaborator on the repo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing an async XHR, then immediately doing a loop trying to use its results.   I have no idea why this possibly works in Chrome, but it's definitely racy.  Have you tried passing "sync:true" in your post options?

Edit: Oh, nevermind.  I see why your code works.  The hive.pollen script has this wonderful bit:

```
sync: navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('safari/') != -1 ? false : true,
```

So it's doing a sync XHR in Chrome/Safari and an async one in everything else, by default (because it passes `options.sync` as the value for the `async` argument to `XMLHttpRequest.open`, which is backwards, but whatever; it does mean that you actually need to pass `sync: false` at the callsite to get sync behavior).  And since you don't specify whether you want sync or async, you get sync in Chrome and async in Firefox.

Oh, and the script has this wonderful comment before that line:

```
//  TODO: FIX THIS.
```

Comment: thanks! i commented out the sync : navigator.userAgent line and replaced it with sync : false. Firefox now works like a charm.

Comment: *alternatively, one could change the name to async: false, and like you said, options.sync to options.async

Comment: So, I haven't really _cared_ about that project in a long time - if someone wants to take it over and whip it into shape (because, frankly, it sucks) then by all means, step forward and I will make you a collaborator on the repo.